# How is \b implemented?

Tags: c, backspace

I have the following program in which I'm trying to understand the functioning of `\b` escape sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int disp(char *a) 
{
    return printf("%s", a); 
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "Hello\b\b";

    printf(" %d\n", disp(s));
    printf("%s %d\n", s, strlen(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Hel 7
Hel 7
$
```

As expected `Hello\b\b` prints `Hell` but the `strlen()` returns 7 which includes the two `\b` characters.

As per C99 5.2.2 `\b` is defined as follows:

```
\b (backspace) Moves the active position to the 
   previous position on the current line. If the 
   active position is at the initial position of 
   a line, the behavior of the display device is 
   unspecified.
```

How is `\b` interpreted in string-related functions like `strlen()`? Are `\b` and other escape sequences resolved at compile time or run time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\b` is a character just like any other in your program. It only becomes special when the terminal sees it.

The characters below ASCII 32 are called "control characters" for a reason: They are a signal to the display device, i.e. your terminal or console, that it should do something special, like beep (`\a`), move the cursor backwards (`\b`) or to the next tab stop (`\t`).

Comment: Actually, they're called "control characters".  "Escape" refers to a specific control character used to alter the meaning of subsequent characters.

Comment: (Good post otherwise -- I gave it a +1)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved during run time. The length of the string includes the `\b` length, but the "rendering engine", the console, is displaying/executing the backspace.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` will go over the char pointer given as an argument until it finds 0.

But `\b` is not 0, this is why you see what you see.

The action linked to this character, however, is linked to your output device.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` only affects output. All string functions will still see it as a character. When your `"Hello\b\b", 7` get displayed, this is what happens (with _ signifying the cursor position):

```
H_
He_
Hel_
Hell_
Hello_
Hell_o  - cursor moves backwards
Hel_lo  - cursor moves backwards
Hel _o  - the space overwrites the "l"
Hel 7_  - the "7" overwrites the "o"
```